# What protocols are supported by the AWS CLI for files?

Tags: amazon-web-services, protocols, aws-cli

I am running the following command and was wondering how else the value for `--template-body` can be specified.

```
aws cloudformation validate-template --template-body file://my-template.yml
```

I know of `http://` and `file://` but are there others? Is there a list of these somewhere?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AWSCLI supports `file:`, `http:`, `https:` protocols.  This is discussed in [this section of the AWSCLI documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-using-param.html).

*Updated*

When in doubt, check the code.  Here are the supported prefixes:

`PREFIX_MAP = {
    'file://': (get_file, {'mode': 'r'}),
    'fileb://': (get_file, {'mode': 'rb'}),
    'http://': (get_uri, {}),
    'https://': (get_uri, {}),
}`

Comment: I'm not too sure about that document. I just did a grep of the aws api and there were other protocols like s3:// s3n:// and fileb:// that aren't discussed there.